# Connect to a SQL Anywhere 5.0 DB from java

Tags: java, jdbc-odbc, sybase-asa

I need to connect to a Billing system which is backed by a SQL Anywhere 5.0 DB and I am pretty much drawing a blank when I try to find a jodbc driver for this.

I was successful in doing this with an upgraded version(SQL Anywhere 11) by using the iAnywhere jodbc drivers that I found in the DB installation folder.

```
DriverManager.registerDriver((Driver) Class.forName("ianywhere.ml.jdbcodbc.jdbc3.IDriver").newInstance());

con = DriverManager.getConnection(String.format("jdbc:ianywhere:dsn=%s;uid=%s;pwd=%s;", dbDsn, dbUser, dbPassword));
```

But, the 5.0 version does not have any JDBC-ODBC drivers.

Also, I need to connect via the odbc way as the DSN is created and managed by the Billing software.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need to connect from your unnamed Java app to the target SQL Anywhere 5.0 DB, through the ODBC DSN maintained by the Billing software.  That means you need a JDBC Driver for ODBC Data Sources, such as [the one from my employer](http://uda.openlinksw.com/jdbc-odbc-st/).  The free two-week trial should be enough for your to figure out whether this will do the job for you.